# WCF & Ninject - Getting Ninject Kernel Into An IDispatchMessageInspector Instance

Tags: wcf, ninject

I've currently rigged up Ninject into a WCF application (using [ninject.extensions.wcf](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf)), and the basics are working fine. However, I've added a custom `IDispatchMessageInspector` and `IServiceBehavior` in order to authenticate each service call (by check the database against some credentials), but I'm not entirely sure how to get Ninject working within the IDispatchMessageInspector.

The code I have so far is:

```
public class MyServiceInspector: IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    #region Methods

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        // TODO: Get credentials from request here, and hit database.

        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        // Do nothing
    } 

   #endregion
}
```

The `IServiceBehavior` which initiates this is as follows:

```
public class MyServiceBehaviour : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    #region Methods

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        // Loop through channels and endpoints
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher cDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher eDispatcher in cDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                // Add credentials inspector
                eDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyServiceInspector());
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I've scoured the internet looking for examples, but I can't seem to find anything. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this answer is very late, but  hopefully it helps other people coming across this issue.

I had the same problem today.. I needed a message inspector with injected dependencies. They added a NinjectBehaviorExtensionElement class to Ninjext.Extensions.WCF from version 3.2. So here's how i injected dependencies in my Message Inspector:

The Message Inspector:

```
 public class MyMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
 {
    public MyMessageInspector(IInjectedDependency injectedDependency)
    {

    }

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
    }
 }
```

The Behavior:

```
public class MyMessageInspectionBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    private readonly IDispatchMessageInspector _messageInspector;

    public MyMessageInspectionBehavior(IDispatchMessageInspector messageInspector)
    {
        _messageInspector = messageInspector;
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(_messageInspector);
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
```

}

The Ninject Binding:

```
this.Bind<IDispatchMessageInspector>()
    .To<MyMessageInspector>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<IEndpointBehavior>();
```

The last step is the Configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="MyCustomMessageInspector" 
         type="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.BaseNinjectBehaviorExtensionElement+NinjectBehaviorExtensionElement`1[[MyNamespace.MyMessageInspectionBehavior, MyAssemblyName]], Ninject.Extensions.Wcf" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <MyCustomMessageInspector />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Comment: Hi, I know this is years later, but I'm wondering will the MyMessageInspector be singleton or a new instance for every request?

Answer (score 0):

I have parked this for now, as there doesn't seem to be any solution. I am simply connecting to my context directly with a view to improving it in the future.